# How to size content relative to screen size in scrollview for Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I have a bunch of buttons I want to stack, but I also want them to be scrollable. How can I set the size of the buttons as a percentage of the actual screen size? I have tried star sizing on a grid layout.

Comment: What do you mean by having both a percentage size and being able to scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go...10 buttons programmatically added to a ScrollView with each button a percentage of the total screen width and height (50% and 20% respectively), along with a click handler...

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Get Screen Dimensions
        var dm = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
        var widthDP = dm.WidthPixels / dm.Density;
        var heightDP = dm.HeightPixels / dm.Density;
        Android.Util.Log.Info("MyApp", $"Screen Width x Screen Height = {widthDP}dp X {heightDP}dp");

        // Add 10 Buttons in a ScrollView
        var sv = new ScrollView(this);            
        var ll = new LinearLayout(this) { Orientation = Android.Widget.Orientation.Vertical };
        sv.AddView(ll);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var btn = new Button(this);
            btn.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Blue);
            btn.Text = $"Button #{i+1}";
            btn.Tag = i+1;
            btn.Click += (sender, e) => {
                Android.Util.Log.Info("MyApp", $"Button # {btn.Tag} + Clicked!");
            };
            // Make each button 50% of the total screen width and 20% of the *total* screen height
            var lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Convert.ToInt32(widthDP * .50), Convert.ToInt32(heightDP * .20));
            lp.SetMargins(0, 10, 0, 0);     // Top margin of 10
            btn.LayoutParameters = lp;
            ll.AddView(btn);
        }

        SetContentView(sv);
    }
```

**ScreenShot**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to do this entirely in xaml?